# SharedPreferences troublesome nullpointerexception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

(REMOVED THE OLD CONTENT OF THE POST)

EDIT #2: Okay, so now I am crystal clear that it is the editor trying to reach the preference that causes the nullpointerexception. Any help here on how to fix it?

Here is the updated activity:

```
     public SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
 Editor editor;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // requesting to turn the title OFF
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    // making it full screen
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    // set our MainGamePanel as the View
    setContentView(new MainGamePanel(this));

 // Restore preferences

        this.sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        this.editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        try {
        int wins = GetPreferences("wins");
        int fails = GetPreferences("fails");
        gamePanel.winn = wins;
        gamePanel.failn = fails;
        } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Nothing to load");
        }

    //INIT SOUND
    mSoundManager.initSounds(getBaseContext());
    //SOUNDS
    mSoundManager.addSound(1, R.raw.draw);
    mSoundManager.addSound(2, R.raw.cheer);
    mSoundManager.addSound(3, R.raw.boo);

}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
    super.onBackPressed();
    if (gamePanel.gamei==true) {
        gamePanel.back();
    } else if (gamePanel.menui==true) {
        finish();
        System.runFinalizersOnExit(true);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

public void onPause() 
{
    super.onPause();
    //KILL ALL
    finish();
    System.runFinalizersOnExit(true);
    System.exit(0);
}

@Override
protected void onStop(){
   super.onStop();
  //KILL ALL
  finish();
  System.runFinalizersOnExit(true);
  System.exit(0);
}

public int GetPreferences(String key) {
    return sharedPreferences.getInt(key, 0);
}

public void SavePreferences(String key, int value) {
editor.putInt(key, value);    
editor.apply();  
} 

public void writeWin () { 
    SavePreferences("wins", gamePanel.winn);
}
public void writeFail () { 
    SavePreferences("fails", gamePanel.failn);
}
```

*The editor is what is causing the nullpointerexception: `this.editor = sharedPreferences.edit();`.* EDIT: It's the sharedPreferences that is causing the nullpointerexception, not the editor.

It seems like the editor cannot reach the Preference: `this.sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);`.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: have you declared a name for your preferences file?

Comment: I don't think so. Where do I do that?

Comment: From where is `writeSettings` called? Perhaps your activity context is gone by the time it is called.

Comment: Can you post the full exception output logs?

Comment: Updated the question. It seems like the editor cannot reach the preference and that's what's causing the `nullpointerexception`. I have no clue on how to fix it, though.

Comment: You might also using getSharedPreferences, which takes your package name (from your manifest) as the first argument.  Shouldn't be any difference since getPreferences just calls getSharedPreferences but it might be worth a shot.

Comment: `public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";`
it will create a file named MyPrefsFile where all of your prefs will be saved. Place it above `public SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;`
I hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: I put `public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";` above `public SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;` and changed `getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE)` to `getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE)` but it didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it fixed by using a listener! It apparantely was the gamePanel that was null inside of the activity. Go here for more information:
[nullpointerexception when trying to reach activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439377/nullpointerexception-when-trying-to-reach-activity)

Answer (score 0):

It look like the declaration

Editor editor;

should be

SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

Comment: I belive that hasn't to do with the exception. Editor is the same as SharedPreferences.Editor. It's the preference that seem to be null. That's what I would like an answer for. Why does it become null?

Comment: So it is your sharedPreferences is null, isn't it? I copy your code minus the gamePanel and has no problem running it. Maybe you should check your gamePanel.

Comment: Well there should be no problem running it, since nothing tries to reach the sharedPreferences yet. I've tried putting the calls to the writeWin and writeFail functions inside of the activity's stop and pause functions but it ends up with the same exception. Try calling the `writeWin();` `writeFail();` calls inside of the onStop function and you'll see that you will get an error when you quit the app.